# How to make SNS notification for CodeCommit in CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services

AWS::CodeCommit::Repository have only triggers section.

```
Type: AWS::CodeCommit::Repository
Properties: 
  Code: 
    Code
  RepositoryDescription: String
  RepositoryName: String
  Tags: 
    - Tag
  Triggers: 
    - RepositoryTrigger
```

How to add notifications to a repository? Where is option for notifications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notifications for `CodeCommit` are part of `AWS CodeStar Notifications`:

- [Introducing notifications for AWS CodeCommit, AWS CodeBuild, AWS CodeDeploy, and AWS CodePipeline](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/11/introducing-notifications-for-aws-codecommit-aws-codebuild-aws-codedeploy-and-asw-codepipeline/).
- [What Are Notifications?](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codestar-notifications/latest/userguide/welcome.html)

Therefore, you use them through [AWS::CodeStarNotifications::NotificationRule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-codestarnotifications-notificationrule.html).